# JWT-Authentication of mulitple Laravel-APIs with the same token

Tags: laravel, jwt

I have a laravel / angular app secured with tymon/jwt-auth.

Now I need a seperate Laravel (or Lumen) API. I want this API to accept the same tokens as the first one. I assumed that this would work if I would set the same secret and mount the middleware.

It doesn't. Using a freshly generated token I can query the first API but not the new one. Why is that? Is something else besides the secret used to verify the token?

What would be a good way to make this work? I would not mind to make a completely new authentication.

Edit: So it seems like a connection to the database is need to verify the token. Maybe it checks if the user specified in the token is actually present in the DB?

Edit2: Tore Nestenius commented about Aud-Claims. I wanted to go to the config/jwt.php file to check on that. But I had forgotten to create one. Now it works.

Comment: Can you post your API configuration and a sample token? perhaps the aud claim in the token does not match?

Comment: Thanks for your help. As you can read in my edit, it helped me solve the issue. If you create an answer, I will approve it.

Comment: This is not the way to validate a token. First check if the JWT is well formed, second check the signature, and last you check the standard claims.

Comment: The actual validation of the token is handled by the package. The config for that package was missing. Including the config for the aud-claims.

But the process will most likely have failed before getting to the aud-claims.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **aud** claim in the token must match what both API's expect to see in the access token. I am glad my comment helped you to solve your issue.